# Check radio button before opening mini browser jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal

Hi i have used paypal's adaptive payment and it opens mini browser when I click on pay button, but I want it to be opened only if the radio is checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var returnFromPayPal = function() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'room_booking/success_handler' ;?>",
        data: {
            'roomdata': roomData,
            'userdata': userData
        },
        success: function(response) {
            document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';

            if (response == 'cancelled') {

                $("#paymentError").html('<span class="disablebtnInfo" id="msg" style="display:block;margin-left: 40%;"><span class="error_sign">Oops  !</span>&nbsp;<span id="errmsg">Your payment was interrupted, please make sure your payment</span></span></strong>');
            } else {
                $("#step3").removeClass("progtrckr-todo").addClass("progtrckr-done");
                $("#step4").removeClass("progtrckr-todo").addClass("progtrckr-done");
                $("#replaceMe").html(response);
            }

        }
    });

    // Here you would need to pass on the payKey to your server side handle to call the PaymentDetails API to make sure Payment has been successful or not
    // based on the payment status- redirect to your success or cancel/failed urls
};
var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini({
    trigger: 'submitBtn',
    expType: 'mini',
    callbackFunction: 'returnFromPayPal'
});
</script>
```

How to do that

Comment: is the radio button from within the returned data in the HTML or you have it on screen? can you explain what radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the radio button is a piece of HTML on the page, such as , and that you are using jquery, then put your $.ajax() call inside a test of the radio button, e.g.:

```
if ($('#dopaypal').val()) {
    $.ajax(...)
}
```